# How to test a Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 application, and I am wondering how can I see if my .xap file will cause or not a crash.

You will tell me that I can put it into a asp web server and launch Firefox but I would like to stay offline, just with a command line...

Do you have some idea ?

Thanks a lot !
I hope i was clear enought !

Answer (score 0):

Set the application to run Out of Browser (OOB).

Right Click your project -> Properties -> Silverlight -> Check the box for Enable running application out of the browser and optionally change some of the settings for out of browser.

Comment: Ok, I got it with SLLauncher.exe.
But How can I have the return code and verify I the application have crashed or not ?